# best tools to parse multi line *.dat record to single row

Tags: python, postgresql, csv

Looking for some insights on the best tools to process multiline txt records into a single row to input to a Postgresql db.

Data is in a *.dat file in the format;

```
B;666;4148672;2;20200803 01:04;;;5;AQUARIUS;VIRGO;2345470;1000;M;20200714;20200724;150000;R2;V;XX;;AFE;;0;ZZZZ396;
C;666;4148672;2;20200803 01:04;117-508A, 385-404B, 2-5A-C4387, 564654-25, 564654-24;
C;666;4148672;2;20200803 01:04;546654-28, 42785A-B-8, 44915-8-4;
D;666;4148672;2;20200803 01:04;P;;;;;;
D;666;4148672;2;20200803 01:04;V;;;;;;
B;666;4148672;3;20200803 01:04;;;5;TAURUS;AIRIES;586559;1000;M;20200714;20200724;150000;R2;V;XX;;AFE;;0;ZZZZ396;
C;666;4148672;3;20200803 01:04;5587T-33, 5454X-A;
D;666;4148672;3;20200803 01:04;P;;;;;;
D;666;4148672;3;20200803 01:04;V;;;;;;
B;667;4148672;1;20200803 01:04;;;5;AERO;GUNYA;586559;1000;M;20200714;20200724;150000;R2;V;XX;;AFE;;0;ZZZZ396;
C;667;4148672;1;20200803 01:04;8978-4;
D;667;4148672;1;20200803 01:04;P;;;;;;
D;667;4148672;1;20200803 01:04;V;;;;;;
```

That is 3 records.

The delimiter is semi-colon which is pretty reliable. I have a good understanding of what all the fields are. The file has a header row, A which gives a date, and the final row is Z which gives a count of all the records. The first column shown here, B, C, D denotes attributes which must be concatenated, the C row can be repeated one or more times to create a field with ~1000 characters. Seemingly the author has a limit to how many characters it can write in any one line.

Obviously I'd be pleased if a reply contained a complete solution, but my question is;

*what are the tools that will deal with this? Possibly this format is not unique?*

Use case will be automated on a server, python would be available, as is postgresql.

---

Edited to show 3 records.

Comment: This looks surprisingly similar to a CSV file. I would try to process it as a CSV I believe.

Comment: I agree with @Marek Puchalski. Since you mention Python, I would take a look at [Copy From](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from) in ```psycopg2```. If you have any specific questions about the preceding, add them to you initial question.

Comment: Agree it is a csv / txt file. I have edited to expand on the example. The challenge is breaking it down into a one row per record. I have done this in a spreadsheet but thats a hack. Note that the index of a new record is 4 columns in and is actually a combination of the 4th and 2nd column.

Comment: I will change the title - to include `parse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for, though if you could provide a sample output I could edit this as needed. (What are the three lines supposed to be?) Here I've concatenated lines if they start with something other than B.

```
with open('myfile.txt') as file_handle:
    file_content = file_handle.read()

list_of_lines = []
concatenated_line = ""
for line in file_content.split('\n'):
    if line.startswith('B'):
        if len(concatenated_line)>0:
            list_of_lines.append(concatenated_line)
        concatenated_line = line
    else:
        concatenated_line+=line
list_of_lines.append(concatenated_line)
      
for line in list_of_lines:
    print(line.split(';'))
```

Which produces the output

```
['B', '666', '4148672', '2', '20200803 01:04', '', '', '5', 'AQUARIUS', 'VIRGO', '2345470', '1000', 'M', '20200714', '20200724', '150000', 'R2', 'V', 'XX', '', 'AFE', '', '0', 'ZZZZ396', 'C', '666', '4148672', '2', '20200803 01:04', '117-508A, 385-404B, 2-5A-C4387, 564654-25, 564654-24', 'C', '666', '4148672', '2', '20200803 01:04', '546654-28, 42785A-B-8, 44915-8-4', 'D', '666', '4148672', '2', '20200803 01:04', 'P', '', '', '', '', '', 'D', '666', '4148672', '2', '20200803 01:04', 'V', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['B', '666', '4148672', '3', '20200803 01:04', '', '', '5', 'TAURUS', 'AIRIES', '586559', '1000', 'M', '20200714', '20200724', '150000', 'R2', 'V', 'XX', '', 'AFE', '', '0', 'ZZZZ396', 'C', '666', '4148672', '3', '20200803 01:04', '5587T-33, 5454X-A', 'D', '666', '4148672', '3', '20200803 01:04', 'P', '', '', '', '', '', 'D', '666', '4148672', '3', '20200803 01:04', 'V', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['B', '667', '4148672', '1', '20200803 01:04', '', '', '5', 'AERO', 'GUNYA', '586559', '1000', 'M', '20200714', '20200724', '150000', 'R2', 'V', 'XX', '', 'AFE', '', '0', 'ZZZZ396', 'C', '667', '4148672', '1', '20200803 01:04', '8978-4', 'D', '667', '4148672', '1', '20200803 01:04', 'P', '', '', '', '', '', 'D', '667', '4148672', '1', '20200803 01:04', 'V', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

Comment: Thank @Ben! I copied it into a spreadsheet, mostly the columns line up. Yes the lines are now one record each which was is the key to the format.